# effective backup strategy with storage reuse but without duplicates

Tags: python, algorithm, language-agnostic, backup

I'm trying to figure out how to implement an automatic backup file naming/recycling strategy that keeps older backup files but with decreasing frequency over time. The basic idea is that it would be possible to remove at maximum one file when adding a new one, but I was not successful implementing this from scratch.

That's why I started to try out the [Grandfather-Father-Son](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup_rotation_scheme#Grandfather-father-son) pattern, but there is not a requirement to stick to this. I started my experiments using a single pool, but I failed more than once, so I started again from this more descriptive approach using four pools, one for each frequency:<sup>[1]</sup>

```
import datetime

t = datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1, 5, 0, 0) # start at 1st of Jan 2001, at 5:00 am
d = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

days = []
weeks = []
months = []
years = []

def pool_it(t):
    days.append(t)
    if len(days) > 7: # keep not more than seven daily backups
        del days[0]
    if (t.weekday() == 6):
        weeks.append(t)
        if len(weeks) > 5: # ...not more than 5 weekly backups
            del weeks[0]
    if (t.day == 28):
        months.append(t)
        if len(months) > 12: # ... limit monthly backups
            del months[0]
    if (t.day == 28 and t.month == 12):
        years.append(t)
        if len(years) > 10: # ... limit yearly backups...
            del years[0]

for i in range(4505):
    pool_it(t)
    t += d

no = 0
def print_pool(pool, rt):
    global no
    print("----")
    for i in pool:
        no += 1
        print("{:3}  {}  {}".format(no, i.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %a"), (i-rt).days))

print_pool(years, t)
print_pool(months,t)
print_pool(weeks,t)
print_pool(days,t)
```

The output shows that there are duplicates, marked with `*` and `**`

```
----
  1  2003-12-28 Sun  -3414
  2  2004-12-28 Tue  -3048
  3  2005-12-28 Wed  -2683
  4  2006-12-28 Thu  -2318
  5  2007-12-28 Fri  -1953
  6  2008-12-28 Sun  -1587
  7  2009-12-28 Mon  -1222
  8  2010-12-28 Tue  -857
  9  2011-12-28 Wed  -492
 10  2012-12-28 Fri  -126 *
----
 11  2012-05-28 Mon  -340
 12  2012-06-28 Thu  -309
 13  2012-07-28 Sat  -279
 14  2012-08-28 Tue  -248
 15  2012-09-28 Fri  -217
 16  2012-10-28 Sun  -187
 17  2012-11-28 Wed  -156
 18  2012-12-28 Fri  -126 *
 19  2013-01-28 Mon  -95
 20  2013-02-28 Thu  -64
 21  2013-03-28 Thu  -36
 22  2013-04-28 Sun  -5 **
----
 23  2013-03-31 Sun  -33
 24  2013-04-07 Sun  -26
 25  2013-04-14 Sun  -19
 26  2013-04-21 Sun  -12
 27  2013-04-28 Sun  -5 **
----
 28  2013-04-26 Fri  -7
 29  2013-04-27 Sat  -6
 30  2013-04-28 Sun  -5 **
 31  2013-04-29 Mon  -4
 32  2013-04-30 Tue  -3
 33  2013-05-01 Wed  -2
 34  2013-05-02 Thu  -1
```

...which is not a big problem. What I'm getting from it is daily backups in the last week, weekly backups for the last month, monthly backups for the last year, and yearly backups for 10 years. The amount of files is always limited to 10+12+5+7=34.

My ideal solution would

- create files with human-readable names including timestampes (i.e. `xyz-yyyy-mm-dd.bak`)
- use only one pool (store/remove files within one folder)
- recycle targeted, that is, would not delete more than one file a day
- (naturally) not contain any duplicates

Do you have a trivial solution at hand or a suggestion where to learn more about it?

---

<sup>[1]</sup> I used python as to better understand/communicate my question, but the question is about the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

As a committer of [pyExpireBackups](https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/pyExpireBackups) i can point you to the ExpirationRule implementation of my solution (source below and in the github repo)

see https://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/PyExpireBackups for the doku.

An example run would lead to:

```sh
keeping 7 files for dayly backup
keeping 6 files for weekly backup
keeping 8 files for monthly backup
keeping 4 files for yearly backup
expiring 269 files dry run
#   1✅:   0.0 days(    5 GB/    5 GB)→./sql_backup.2022-04-02.tgz
#   2✅:   3.0 days(    5 GB/    9 GB)→./sql_backup.2022-03-30.tgz
#   3✅:   4.0 days(    5 GB/   14 GB)→./sql_backup.2022-03-29.tgz
#   4✅:   5.0 days(    5 GB/   18 GB)→./sql_backup.2022-03-28.tgz
#   5✅:   7.0 days(    5 GB/   23 GB)→./sql_backup.2022-03-26.tgz
#   6✅:   9.0 days(    5 GB/   27 GB)→./sql_backup.2022-03-24.tgz
#   7✅:  11.0 days(    5 GB/   32 GB)→./sql_backup.2022-03-22.tgz
#   8❌:  15.0 days(    5 GB/   37 GB)→./sql_backup.2022-03-18.tgz
#   9❌:  17.0 days(    5 GB/   41 GB)→./sql_backup.2022-03-16.tgz
#  10✅:  18.0 days(    5 GB/   46 GB)→./sql_backup.2022-03-15.tgz
#  11❌:  19.0 days(    5 GB/   50 GB)→./sql_backup.2022-03-14.tgz
#  12❌:  20.0 days(    5 GB/   55 GB)→./sql_backup.2022-03-13.tgz
#  13❌:  22.0 days(    5 GB/   59 GB)→./sql_backup.2022-03-11.tgz
#  14❌:  23.0 days(    5 GB/   64 GB)→./sql_backup.2022-03-10.tgz
#  15✅:  35.0 days(    4 GB/   68 GB)→./sql_backup.2022-02-26.tgz
#  16❌:  37.0 days(    4 GB/   73 GB)→./sql_backup.2022-02-24.tgz
#  17❌:  39.0 days(    4 GB/   77 GB)→./sql_backup.2022-02-22.tgz
#  18❌:  40.0 days(    5 GB/   82 GB)→./sql_backup.2022-02-21.tgz
#  19✅:  43.0 days(    4 GB/   86 GB)→./sql_backup.2022-02-18.tgz
...
```

```py
class ExpirationRule():
    '''
    an expiration rule keeps files at a certain 
    '''
    def __init__(self,name,freq:float,minAmount:int):
        '''
        constructor
        
        name(str): name of this rule
        freq(float): the frequency) in days
        minAmount(int): the minimum of files to keep around
        '''
        self.name=name
        self.ruleName=name # will late be changed by a sideEffect in getNextRule e.g. from "week" to "weekly"
        self.freq=freq
        self.minAmount=minAmount
        if minAmount<0:
            raise Exception(f"{self.minAmount} {self.name} is invalid - {self.name} must be >=0")
        
    def reset(self,prevFile:BackupFile):
        '''
        reset my state with the given previous File
        
        Args:
            prevFile: BackupFile - the file to anchor my startAge with
        '''
        self.kept=0
        if prevFile is None:
            self.startAge=0 
        else:
            self.startAge=prevFile.ageInDays
        
    def apply(self,file:BackupFile,prevFile:BackupFile,debug:bool)->bool:
        '''
        apply me to the given file taking the previously kept File prevFile (which might be None) into account
        
        Args:
        
            file(BackupFile): the file to apply this rule for
            prevFile(BackupFile): the previous file to potentially take into account
            debug(bool): if True show debug output
        '''
        if prevFile is not None:
            ageDiff=file.ageInDays - prevFile.ageInDays
            keep=ageDiff>=self.freq
        else:
            ageDiff=file.ageInDays - self.startAge
            keep=True
        if keep:
            self.kept+=1
        else:
            file.expire=True
        if debug:
            print(f"Δ {ageDiff}({ageDiff-self.freq}) days for {self.ruleName}({self.freq}) {self.kept}/{self.minAmount}{file}")
        return self.kept>=self.minAmount
```

Comment: Thank you so much for stopping by (for such an old question!) I have solved my problem (sort of). I hope to find the time to take a closer look at your solution soon.

Comment: @Wolf - thanks for the upvote and comment. The opensource solution pyExpireBackups has evolved from a shell script https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/pyExpireBackups/issues/1 that was created almost 20 years ago to a Java Solution in 2008 and the refactoring to pyExpireBackups was done by me this weekend. I like the python solution much better since it's shorter cleaner and better testable. Currently i only compare two file for the expiration decisision. The algorithm you proposed to go pool by pool basically is compatible with this ExpirationRule idea and could work on list of files if wanted.

Comment: The funny thing about this info is that, for my part, I actually needed a solution for C++. I tried to work out the details in Python first, which was much easier to do.